# How to pass an object from a JSP form to an Action class in Struts2 without defining all form fields as a class property?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

To make the question clear I make an example:

1. consider `theSubscriber` form defined bellow in `first.jsp`:

   ```xml
   <s:form id="theSubscriber" name="theSubscriber" method="post" action="next.action">
       <s:bean name="my.hibernate.actors.Subscriber" var="user">
           <s:hidden name="id" key="id" value="%{user.id}"  />
           <s:textfield id="subscriberForename" name="forename"
                       key="forename" value="%{user.forename}" label="Forename" />
           <s:textfield id="subscriberSurname" name="surname" 
                       key="surname" value="%{user.surname}" label="Surname" />
       </s:bean>
   </s:form>
   ```
2. consider the following action class for the next.action

   ```
   public class NextAction extends ActionSupport {

       private Subscriber user = new Subscriber();

       private String forename;

       public String getForename() {
           return forename;
       }        
       public void setForename(String forename) {
           this.forename = forename;
       }

       public ManageSubscriber() {
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }

       public ManageSubscriber(Subscriber user) {
           this.user = user;
       }

       public Subscriber getUser() {
           return user;
       }                
       public void setUser(Subscriber user) {
           this.user = user;
       }

       public String execute() {
           System.out.println(getUser());//This prints out null
           System.out.println(getForename());//This prints out the posted forename
           return SUCCESS;
       }
   }
   ```
3. The question is: I know that defining all the form fields as action class properties let the class fill them correctly. But I want to make it fill the relevant fields in another class which contains all necessary properties. The user/subscriber class is like this:

   ```
   public class User {
       private long id;
       private String username;
       private String password;
       private UserLevel userLevel;
       private String forename;
       private String surname;
       private String email;
       private String phoneNumber;
       private String address;
       private Date birthday;
       private Date registrationDate;
   }
   ```

I have defined all accessor methods. 
In fact the problem is that it looks very annoying and redundant to define all these fields for the `nextAction` class and then evaluate the instance of user in that class.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is easier than you think.

You are very close, and you've already done it for `value` attribute (used to pre-set the value for the item on the page): 
now just do it for `name` attribute (used to send the value to the Action), like this:

```
<s:hidden name="user.id" key="id" value="%{user.id}"  />
<s:textfield id="subscriberForename" name="user.forename"
    value="%{user.forename}" label="Forename" />
<s:textfield id="subscriberSurname" name="user.surname" 
    value="%{user.surname}" label="Surname" />
```

(`Key` attribute was not necessary here)

Note that for this to work, you will need a bean with a no-args constructor (as you have).

Avoid initializating it yourself too.

Change this:

```
private Subscriber user = new Subscriber();
```

to this

```
private Subscriber user;
```

Comment: Thanks. Così funziona bene! :D You pointed the problem very accurately!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how you can persist in memory a User object that will be used across multiple actions.

You have a couple of options if I understand your question correctly.

One option, which is not very Struts like, would be to add the User object to a session variable. You can access the session variable as described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-get-the-httpservletrequest-in-struts-2/).

Another option, which I would recommend if you plan on maintaining the object in your session for a specific set of actions (or steps, such as a 'wizard' portion of your app) is the ScopeInterceptor.  You can read about that [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ScopeInterceptor.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441702/scope-interceptor-in-struts2).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your post was generaly useful for me and I learnt some interesting things but I didn't mean such this thing. I'm looking to know if struts has an automated way for initializing a java object defined as an attribute in an action class! If you have a look at my example it will become more obvious. I want to avoid redefining all user class attributes in the action class. I expect struts to do it for me!