# How to redirect with parameter

Tags: struts2, query-string, post-redirect-get

```xml
<action name="AddedPaid"  class="iland.payment.SupplierPaidAction" method="insert">
  <result name="success"  type="redirect">ShowPaid</result>
  <result name="input">/pages/payment/addToPay.jsp</result>
  <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result> 
</action>   

<action name="ShowPaid" class="iland.payment.SupplierPaidAction" method="fetchAllByfk">
        <result name="success">/pages/paid/showPaidDetails.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/pages/payment/ShowPay.jsp</result>
        <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>            
 </action>
```

Here `AddedPaid` Action is used to add form data in to database.
After adding data in to database I am redirecting result to `ShowPaid` action.
This is working properly.
Now I want whenever I redirect `AddedPaid` action to `ShowPaid`.
`ShowPaid` must show data of perticular `supplierPaymentId` for which I have added data in `AddedPaid`.

After redirect it is howing url

```
http://localhost:8082/ClothStore/ShowPaid
```

I want

```
http://localhost:8082/ClothStore/ShowPaid?supplierPaymentId=4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's strange, usually people have 2 and want 1 :)

Btw, since you are using PostRedirectGet, you need to manually pass the parameter in Struts configuration.

Assuming you have a variable named `supplierPaymentId` with getter and setter, it's achievable like follows:

```xml
<action name="AddedPaid" class="iland.payment.SupplierPaidAction" method="insert">
    <result name="success"  type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">ShowPaid</param>
        <param name="supplierPaymentId">${supplierPaymentId}</param>
    </result>  
    <result name="input">/pages/payment/addToPay.jsp</result>
    <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

Also use redirectAction instead of redirect, that is meant to be used to redirect to external URLs or non-Action URLs

Comment: Can we pass `actionErrors' and 'actionMessages' in same way

Comment: No, because they're Lists, not Strings. You can save them in session in first action and retrieve them in second one, or use the [Scope Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html) that [does that for you automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8442045/1654265).

Comment: 6 years later and solved my own issue perfectly. +1 for aiding my "legacy" support :)

Comment: Glad that helped @NickReed :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all use `redirectAction` result instead of `redirect` to redirect to another action.
And use `param` tag to add parameters in your result configuration.

```xml
<result type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">ShowPaid</param>
    <param name="supplierPaymentId">${supplierPaymentId}</param>
</result>
```

Note you need to have getter/setter for `supplierPaymentId` in your action class.